# Simple questions about python Jabber, Twisted, XMLRPC, and SCP

Tags: python, twisted, xmpp, scp

I have a few questions about these protocols that I am having a really hard time answering just searching the web. So here goes. Please excuse my ignorance in advance, I know at least one of these questions will make you cringe.

SCP: Does the SSH file transfer protocol guarantee the correct data will get there is the server is running? In essence, if I write a script with scp is it redundant to check a hash of the file after I receive it.

Twisted: I am using Twisted with prospective broker. Same question here, is it redundant to check a hash, if I do a remote call and it returns a good value, can I assume the server not only got data, but it got the correct data? Is this the function of errbacks, or are those for other errors? I will probably test this myself with netstat or something, but is a lot of extra data sent when using PB? Does it have to resend the Avatar over the net every time it calls a remote function?

Jabber: Same thing about guarantees, if I do a send and it returns a good value, can I assume the server not only got data, but it got the correct data? I have seen jabber referred to as "near-real-time." What does that mean, on an order of magnitude, what kind of delays would one expect assuming all clients/servers are on a good connection. I have been running a program that uses jabber and it has been rather crappy for me (has to be restarted from time to time, doesn't always get the data within hours of it being transmitted), are these problems with the protocol, or is code simply poorly written?

XMLRPC: Again with the error correction guarantees. I wrote a SimpleXMLRPCServer/client program in python and it crapped out at 10 requests per second, is that standard, or did I just do a bad job?

Answers to any of these questions would be great, thanks guys.

Edit: I am writing an analysis algorithm which is going to be using one, or some combination of these methods to move datafiles. I am going to be getting a good amount of requests per seconds and speed is an issue.

However, getting incorrect data is unacceptable for this purpose. I was unser the impression TCP did guarantee you're data, but whether or not getting the data in an endpoint means getting it correct on disk, I don't know.

Comment: You have 4 quite unrelated questions, so better split them up into 4 separate questions...

Answer (score 2):

> SCP: Does the SSH file transfer protocol guarantee the correct data will get there is the server is running? In essence, if I write a script with scp is it redundant to check a hash of the file after I receive it.

Generally, *guarantee* is a strong word.

TCP alone *endeavours* to provide reliable delivery, checksums, acknowledgements, sequence numbers, retries together mean that there *shouldn't* be any undetected errors. It doesn't, however withstand malicious interference.

On top of TCP, SSH/SCP *endeavours* to provide secure (host authenticated, encrypted, integrity checked) end to end transmission of data, so that malicious interference is always detected. However, this assumes that you use it correctly, e.g. host key checking.

This is good enough for most use cases.

However, if you want to be triply-sure and to perhaps cover for extremely rare undetected disk errors, read the files and generate secure digests with e.g. sha256sum.

---

You have posted many questions on a similar theme, what is it that you are worried about? Network level errors? Malicious interference?

---

> I wrote a SimpleXMLRPCServer/client program in python and it crapped out at 10 requests per second, is that standard, or did I just do a bad job?

10 per second is a bit low. Are these pipelined (one TCP connection)? If not, you could be hitting a SYN ratelimit somewhere. Compare pipelined performance to separate connections per request.

Comment: I am writing an analysis algorithm which is going to be using one, or some combination of these methods to move datafiles. I am going to be getting a good amount of requests per seconds and speed is an issue.


However, getting incorrect data is unacceptable for this purpose. I was unser the impression TCP did guarantee you're data, but whether or not getting the data in an endpoint means getting it correct on disk, I don't know.